# how to perform magento 1 system cleanup

Tags: magento-1.9, system

I want to perform system cleanup of a Magento 1 store so what steps to be taken care in the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below clean script.

https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php

Run that script manually.